# Footer slides up when cursor at bottom of browser

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I want my footer of the page to slide up onto the screen when my cursor is at the bottom of the browser. I don't have a clue on where to being but here is my CSS code for the footer:

```
footer {
background-color: #333;
position: fixed; 
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 75px;
clear: both;
float:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CSS Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) to change properties' values over a specified duration in order to achieve the *slide-up* effect.

Whether to slide-up/expand the footer:

```css
footer {
  position: fixed; 
  bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
  height: 75px;

  transition: height .2s ease-in; /* Use transition for 'height' or all */
}

footer:hover {
  height: 50%; /* Change the height of the footer as the half of the screen */
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/suzohebu/1/edit)**.

Or to slide-up/display the footer on hover:

```css
footer {
  position: fixed; 
  bottom: -75px; left: 0; right: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  height: 75px;

  transition: all .2s ease-in;
}

footer:hover { bottom: 0; }
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsbin.com/suzohebu/3/edit)**.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this with some jquery by wrapping the footer in a container

```
$(".footer-container").hover(function(){
  $(".footer").stop().animate({"bottom": "0"});    
},function(){
  $(".footer").stop().animate({"bottom": "-75px"});    
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3vh5Y/)